# How to perform an action every time MathJax updates page?

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I have a website which loads its content using `AJAX`, among other things math in `LaTeX` format.

During loading I would like the view to stay at the bottom, for that I use function `scrollBotom()`

I employ `MathJax` to convert loaded code into readable mathematic formulas. Therefore when loading is done following code gets executed

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, ...]);
MathJax.Hub.Queue(scrollBottom);
```

I've noticed, that `MathJax` updates formulas in chunks, not one by one. I  would like the page to be scrolled bottom after each update.

Is there any way to achieve this?

The only one I could think of is to gather fragments of the `AJAX` content and typeset them separately, then scroll each time. Anyway it is not a real solution.

One more thing - maths are typeset after loading all the content, which is not optimal, because `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset"...` after each page update would result in a huge lag.

Fix for that second issue (typesetting on the fly) is also welcome.